# What's causing bluescreens on my new PC?

Tags: bsod, gaming

I recently brought a gaming PC and I am frequently encountering bluescreen problem:
The blue screen message is memory problem detection restart PC to prevent damage to the computer. The following information given below can give more idea.

```
BCCode: 3b
BCP1:   00000000C0000005
BCP2:   FFFFF80002D3BABF
BCP3:   FFFFF88008395C60
BCP4:   0000000000000000
OS Version: 6_1_7600
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
```

Can some please help me with this issue and tell me what can be done to solve this problem?

Full information on the specification of the PC:

- Computer: ACPI x64-based PC
- Disk Drive: Toshiba DT01ACA050 ATA Device
- Display Adaptor: AMD Radeon HD 6450
- DVD/CD-ROM drive: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM
- GH24NSBO ATA DEVICE IDE ATA/ATAPI CONTROLLER:

  - ATA channel 4
  - ATA channel 5
- Intel 7 series/C216 Chipset Family
- SATA AHCI controller- 1E02
- Image Device: A4Tech USB 2.0 PC camera
- Processor : Intel Core i7-3770 CPU 3.40 GHz

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your graphics drivers.  If you recently upgraded to beta drivers, roll back to your previous drivers.

Comment: Do you think if the install window on pc is 64 bit and the program for the graphic card installed in the pc is 32 bit that can cause the prooblem ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having hardware problems.  Try swapping some part of your base system out, e.g. the memory, the mother board, and/or graphics adapter if it is separate.

The cpu is gagging which is often caused by bad memory, but it can also be caused by running the cpu too fast or not matching the memory with the memory bus speed.

See if you can give the hardware back to where you got it and get your money back.

Comment: The best way to approach this would be software first, test the hardware second, then finally mail it back if it's gone bad, if possible.

Comment: Do you think if the install window on pc is 64 bit and the program for the graphic card installed in the pc is 32 bit that can cause the prooblem ?

Answer (score 0):

[Install the Windows Sp1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1), you're still at Windows 7 RTM level which no longer gets updates. If this doesn't fix it, copy the folder C:\Windows\Minidumps, to the desktop, zip and upload the folder to your skydrive/dropbox and post a link here.